# How to restart the export job without restarting whole dcm4chee archive node

Tags: dcm4che

In dcm4chee, I set up a job for exporting the incoming DICOM to other location. Sometimes, if the target location down, say NilRead. even if it resumed, the export job seems still not working. And need to restart the archive docker.

How to restart the export job without restarting whole dcm4chee archive node